# Disadvantage of unlifted type products?

Tags: programming-languages, haskell, types, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

In Haskell, lifted type products mean that there's a semantic difference between (a,b,c) and (a, (b, c)).

If all pattern matches of all products was always irrefutable, then there would be no difference, and (a, b, c) could be syntactic sugar for (a, (b, c)).

Why did Haskell choose to lift type products?

Comment: Because a flatten tuple is less useful?

Comment: By "flatten" do you mean unlifted?  If so, why?  It doesn't seem obvious to me, and the unlifted tuple has better formal algebraic properties.

Comment: I'd rather it to be syntactic sugar for `(a, (b, (c, ())))` like HList

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One reason is that implementing `seq` for an unlifted product requires parallel/interleaved computation, since `seq (a, b) True` would be supposed to be `True` if and only if at least one of `a` and `b` is non-bottom.  You might not find this reason terribly convincing, depending on how you feel about `seq`, but of course polymorphic `seq` is by definition a part of Haskell...

Comment: I think seq should use a type-class, and I think that "seq" in its current form should be allowed to make a diverging program terminate, just not the other way around.

Comment: IOW, I don't really have a problem with  seq (\_|\_, \_|\_) True == True  even if tuples are unlifted.

Comment: At that point, you might as well just not make `(a,b)` an instance of `Seq` (and the same for `a -> b`).

Comment: That may be overly restrictive.  A trivial instance would allow using tuples and functions in more cases even if it means seq is no-op.  I think seq's desirable properties are operational. Does anyone use it for its denotational qualities?

Comment: I have learned the answer to my own question: Yes, people use seq for its denotational semantics. If you want to guarantee a "proof" you've received is indeed a proof.  Though in that case they can just use rnf, which would be valid for most proofs and valid in the (_|_, _|_) case too.

Answer (score 8):

> Why did Haskell choose to lift type products?

You can justify this design choice without appealing to laziness or refutable patterns.
The same design choice is made ML for reasons of supporting polymorphism.  Consider

```
fst (x, y) = x
snd (x, y) = y
```

Now if `(a, (b, c))` is syntactic sugar for `(a, b, c)`, it's quite difficult to see how to specialize `fst` and `snd` to take this type as an argument.  But

```
fst :: (a, (b, c)) -> a
snd :: (a, (b, c)) -> (b, c)
```

are perfectly reasonable.  Because polymorphic functions like `fst` and `snd` are so incredibly useful, both Haskell and ML give the programmer the ability to distinguish `(a, (b, c))` and `((a, b), c)` from `(a, b, c)`.

(For people who care about costs, the type structure is also a reasonable guide to the size of the type and the number of indirections (loads) needed to get its elements.  Some programmers need or want to know about such things and to have some small degree of control over them.)

Comment: You are answering why (a,b,c) is not isomorphic to (a,(b,c)) (or, easier to work with, (a,(b,(c,())))), but not why type products are unlifted.  Lifting means adding a bottom, making (undefined, undefined) distinct from undefined.

Comment: @luqui: Agreed.  I chose to address the part of the question that focuses on the semantic difference between `(a, (b, c))` and `(a, b, c)`.  When that difference is brought into focus, the lifting is obvious---tuples are lifted because *every* type is lifted.

Answer (score 0):

You can produce a semantic difference if you want to in connection with type classes.

`(a, b, c)` and `(a, (b, c))` can instantiate classes differently. Just think of

```
show (1, 2, 3)
```

and

```
show (1, (2, 3))
```

I'd consider it counter-intuitive to have both yielding the same output.

Comment: I really really dislike this. It causes an N-tuple explosion (e.g: see ":info Show" in ghci) and it makes it impossible to instantiate just (a, b) to get instances for all tuples.

I don't really want to have different semantics for (a, b, c) than (a, (b, c)).  I wish show for both just returned "(a, b, c)".

Additionally, the uncomposability of N-tuples is really annoying.

We need to have a bazillion variants of "fst" and "snd", Control.Arrow.first/second, Data.Accessor's tuple accessors, etc.